# OPENROWSET in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Hi i am using OPENROWSET for updating one of the table data but it is giving me error if i pass large number of records can any one tell me how to fix or is there any limit for no of records in open rowset
i read that there is memory size need to be increased but i don't know how to do that and same time is that real reason or some thing else

I am Executing the following query

```
(INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('MSDASQL', 'Driver=PostgreSQL ANSI;uid=postgres;Server=localhost;port=5432;database=xx;pwd=xx', 
'SELECT SanctionId,SchemeType,SchemeCode,ReceivedDate,htmlString 
from releases 
WHERE SanctionId = ''-1'' ') 
SELECT SanctionId,SchemeType,SchemeCode,ReceivedDate,htmlString 
from releases)
```

I am getting following error:

> "OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.". Msg 7344, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)" could not INSERT INTO table "[MSDASQL]" because of column "htmlstring". Could not convert the data value due to reasons other than sign mismatch or overflow. Location: qxcntxt.cpp:1067 Expression: cref == 0 SPID: 54 Process ID: 1832 "

Comment: Can you **show us** what you're doing, and tell us the **exact error** you're getting (and where)??

Comment: Hi thank you i am really sorry about acceptance,i just did it now

Comment: I am getting following error "OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.".
Msg 7344, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)" could not INSERT INTO table "[MSDASQL]" because of column "htmlstring". Could not convert the data value due to reasons other than sign mismatch or overflow.
Location:  qxcntxt.cpp:1067
Expression:  cref == 0
SPID:   54
Process ID:  1832
"

Comment: I am Executing the following query (INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('MSDASQL', 'Driver=PostgreSQL ANSI;uid=postgres;Server=localhost;port=5432;database=xx;pwd=xx',
    'SELECT  SanctionId,SchemeType,SchemeCode,ReceivedDate,htmlString from releases WHERE SanctionId = ''-1'' ')
SELECT SanctionId,SchemeType,SchemeCode,ReceivedDate,htmlString from releases)